# Write the expression as a complete square & using that find the factors

Tags: factoring, square-numbers

Write $x^2+2ax+a^2$ as a complete square

Using that find factors of $x^2+2ax+a^2-9$

I don't know how this should be done & I would highly appreciate your hints

Comment: Factor $x^2+2ax+a^2$; you should end up with a product of two identical factors, i.e., a square. Then factor $x^2+2ax+a^2-9$ as the difference of two squares.

Answer (score 1):

Can you write the first expression as a square?

Now recognise that $9$ is a square also.

Finally, how would you factorise $c^2 - d^2$?